# Javascript: how to join two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this has been asked a lot of times, but I cannot get it to work.

I have an empty array `a`

```
var a = [];
```

and an array with an object `b`

```
var b = [{
   title: 'test'
}]
```

I want to join them so `a` will look exactly like `b`.
The idea is to do this inside a `for loop` so `a` would be added a new item each time.

By using `a.concat(b)`, `a` results in an empty array.

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: please add some use cases. and what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

You need to assign this operation back to `a`

`a = a.concat(b)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign result of that call to a. `a = a.concat(b)`